# Jitsi Meet firewall configuration

Tags: firewall, jitsi

I am currently setting up a Jitsi server and I am running into problems which I suspect stem from the firewall configuration.
The server is an Ubuntu-based machine and I installed Jitsi from the repositories provided by Jitsi.

I added the ports
443, 4443, 5280 (tcp)
and
10000 (udp)
to the firewall, which allows me to connect to the server.

But as soon as I try to join (create) a room, I am being told that I was disconnected and should check my connection.

I assume, the firewall needs some additional ports? Unfortunalty, the Jitsi website and GitHub repository do not provide a full list of all required ports that need to be opened - or did I miss something?

Answer (score 0):

The UDP 10000 is a bit misleading.  It really needs 10000-20000 UDP opened - not just the one one port.  But even with this it may not be the full answer you are looking for.  You are setting up your server on the receiving end of this but are you considering that any of your guest connections to your server also need ports opened?  If they are behind corporate firewalls, etc. they probably won't be able to connect.  You may need to route your connections through some nginx hacks or other ways to use traditionally opened ports here.  This might help:  https://meetrix.io/blog/webrtc/jitsi/jitsi-meet-and-firewalls.html